# What is the usage of ApplicationName property in ClientContext

Tags: csom

ClientContext object has `ApplicationName` property.

Is this property logged anywhere on server in ULS or any other location?

Can this property be used to track different applications connecting to SharePoint?

Can this property be used to restrict access to certain applications?

I have read its documentation on MSDN but I am looking for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Gets or sets the name of the runtime where the current client application is located.

```
SP.ClientContext.set_applicationName(value)
```

**Returns String value** -- The name of the runtime where the current client application is located. When setting this property, the value must be between 1 and 128 characters.

Comment: I have read this from the documentation, I was looking for in depth information

Comment: [http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54472d/introduction-to-sharepoint-client-context-sp-clientcontext/](May be it will helps you but note sure)